# libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file while running tensorflow in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: tensorflow

I have tried cuda 9 but tensorflow doesn't seem to work. Now, I installed cuda 8, set environment variables and other bunch of stuff and still this error persists. Help me out!

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishantsikri/Downloads/tensorflow-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/nishantsikri/Downloads/tensorflow-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/nishantsikri/Downloads/tensorflow-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nishantsikri/Downloads/tensorflow-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/nishantsikri/Downloads/tensorflow-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/nishantsikri/Downloads/tensorflow-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishantsikri/Downloads/tensorflow-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/nishantsikri/Downloads/tensorflow-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/nishantsikri/Downloads/tensorflow-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Find libcublas.so.9.0 in your system, probably under `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64`. Now add to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/cuda/lib64
```

You should then move on from that error and see an error that it can't find `libcudnn.so`. Make sure you've installed the CUDNN library and follow the same procedure for `libcudnn.so` (the actual name of libcudnn is something like libcudnn.so.7 depending on your version).

The key here is setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly.

If you continue to have problems make sure you restart your terminal session and type `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to validate that all setting changes have been applied correctly.

Comment: if LD_LIBRAY_PATH is the variable name for lib64, then what should the variable name be for libcudn.so.##?

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` works just like `PATH`, you separate multiple paths with `:`. Include all folders you need for CUDA and CUDNN to be included (usually that's 2 paths, one for CUDA and another for CUDNN)