# keras and tensorflow are not running on gpu in centos 7

Tags: linux, tensorflow, keras, gpu, centos7

I have been trying to run a NN in keras using tf as backend in a centos 7 server but I got this error:

```
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): install mkl with `conda install mkl-service`: No module named 'mkl'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 1135, in _unify_values
    sectiondict = self._sections[section]
KeyError: 'blas'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 168, in fetch_val_for_key
    return theano_cfg.get(section, option)
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 778, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 1138, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section)
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'blas'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 328, in __get__
    delete_key=delete_key)
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 172, in fetch_val_for_key
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'blas.ldflags'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1250, in check_mkl_openmp
    import mkl
ImportError: No module named 'mkl'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ffnnecodata2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Activation, Dropout, Reshape
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from .theano_backend import *
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 7, in <module>
    import theano
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import (scan, map, reduce, foldl, foldr, clone,
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/scan_module/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from theano.scan_module import scan_opt
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_opt.py", line 60, in <module>
    from theano import tensor, scalar
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/tensor/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from theano.tensor import blas
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas.py", line 155, in <module>
    from theano.tensor.blas_headers import blas_header_text
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/tensor/blas_headers.py", line 987, in <module>
    if not config.blas.ldflags:
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 332, in __get__
    val_str = self.default()
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1447, in default_blas_ldflags
    check_mkl_openmp()
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1262, in check_mkl_openmp
    """)
RuntimeError:
Could not import 'mkl'.  Either install mkl-service with conda or set
MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU in your environment for MKL 2018.

If you have MKL 2017 install and are not in a conda environment you
can set the Theano flag blas.check_openmp to False.  Be warned that if
you set this flag and don't set the appropriate environment or make
sure you have the right version you *will* get wrong results.
```

I'm using a conda environment and I tried to install mkl=2017 but it did not work.

I decided to translate my code to tensorflow and tried to run it again, but I got this message now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorffnnecodata.py", line 17, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init
.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python
_init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python
ywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python
ywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python
ywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python
ywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_modu
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/powerBuilding/anaconda3/envs/tensorgpu/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dyna
c
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Do you know what is wrong with my installation?

Comment: Same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499370/libcublas-so-9-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-while-running-tensorflow-in-ubu/49499804#49499804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that you need to install cuDNN 7.0 (https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) for the version of Cuda you have installed from nVidia website and copy over the files to your Cuda installation folder. Prebuilt binaries of Tensorflow 1.7.0+ requires CUDA 9.0

```
ImportError: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```